# Rss reader Android

Tags: android, rss-reader

I am a new in Android programming and I don't know how to show only given items in listView for Rss reader. I want to show items only for clicked feed, because when I refresh my feeds in listview are show all items for all feeds. How to resolve this problem? Sorry, if I not explain it clear. 
This is my Loader, which load rss items in ListView when you clicked on some feed:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {

    return new ItemsCursorLoader(getApplicationContext(),
            ((SmartRSSApp) getApplication()).getItemsDB());

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}

public static final class ItemsCursorLoader extends SimpleCursorLoader {
    private ItemsDB items;

    public ItemsCursorLoader(Context context, ItemsDB items) {
        super(context);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        return items.getItemsCursor();

    }

}
```

Here is Intent, which start Activity with items in ListView:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RssNewsActivity.class));
}
```

I will appreciate all answers.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use/look at https://github.com/HoloAddict/Flym.
It works like a charm but it has a big codebase as a beginner, anyways with some changes you can make it only load the website RSS you want.